# How to determine lowest integer multiple for any given decimal fraction

Tags: integer-programming

In the equation `a * b = c`, given `a`, how can I find the lowest integer `c` provided that:

- `a` is a terminating decimal
- `b` is an integer

Here is an example:

- a = `0.2525`, b = `400`, c = `101`

---

I realize that I can multiply the decimal by 10^(decimal length) for primes, but how do I find the answer for non-primes? Am I overthinking this?

Comment: What is given? Does not $a=0.1$, $b=10$, $c=1$ work?

Comment: @anderstood You're right; I edited the question to clarify. The title sums it up, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write $a=\dfrac{c}{b}$ as an irreductible fraction, and this will give you the lowest integer $c$ and $b$.

Example: $a=0.2525=\dfrac{2525}{10000}=\dfrac{101}{400}$ yields $b=400$ and $c=101$. $c$ is minimal because $b,c$ are coprime integers.

Comment: But that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how to determine what the value of C is given A in my equation. How do I get to the reduction?

Comment: @JesseJackson That's what I am answering. I added an example. Given $a$, you get $c$ (and also of course $b$ which is determined by $a$ and $c$).

Comment: @anderstood: I understand OP to mean, what is the algorithm to reduce a given fraction $a/b$ to lowest terms.  OP: You need an algorithm for finding the GCD of two integers; you then divide both numerator and denominator by the GCD.  [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) works well.

Comment:  Perfect. That is what I am looking for! Thanks.